# MSVC _Crt* Macros Are not Safe to use in RAII Code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The code below produces a memory leak when there is none. Is it safe to say that Microsoft missed the mark on this one?

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

template <typename T>
class class_leak
{
private:
    T *p_;

public:
    class_leak(T *p) :
        p_(p)
    {}

    ~class_leak()
    {
        delete p_;
    }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
    int *x = new int(10);
    class_leak<int> cl(x);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

---

Prodcues:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{56} normal block at 0x000D1540, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > 0A 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[4584] unique_ptr.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: The destructor for `cl` won't be called until after the call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`.

Comment: So the obvious thing to change is to enclose the variable in a new block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak detection is indeed a bit simplistic. It checks just the current balance of allocations, not what memory can still be freed. Doesn't need RAII or even C++ to demonstrate that:

```
int *p = malloc(10);
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
free(p);
```